# Is this algorithm running on O(n) or O(n^2) for sliding window?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

```
class Solution:

    def maximum_of_all_subarrays_of_size_k(self,arr,k):
        j = k
        overall_max = float('-inf')
        for i in range(0, len(arr)-k+1):
            sub_arr = arr[i:j]
            print(f"maximum of current {sub_arr} is {max(sub_arr)}")
            current_max = max(sub_arr)
            overall_max = max(overall_max, current_max)
            j+=1

        return overall_max





if __name__ == "__main__":
    sol = Solution()
    arr = [8, 5, 10, 7, 9, 4, 15, 12, 90, 13] 
    k = 3
    print(sol.maximum_of_all_subarrays_of_size_k(arr,k))
```

Would like to know if I'm correct in assuming the run time to be 0(n), what's confusing me is the array slicing part.

Answer (score 1):

With `arr[i:j]` this code takes all slices of the list that have size . Taking a slice has a O() time complexity, where  is the size of the slice. Also performing `max` on that slice is O().

There are  −  such slices, so the overall time complexity is O(( − )).

If you want to exclude the  factor from this, then note that for a very small  this is about O(), and when  is close to  then also this is about O(). But when  is like /2, we get O(( − /2)/2) = O(²). So that would be the worst case time complexity in terms of  only.